# Office 365 : CSWP & Display template : display custom image when no results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, display-template, cswp

I'm a little stuck on a problem where i'm sure you could help me :

**What i want :**

I want to add a Content Search Webpart to a page, which check all the items added today in a certain Image Library called BIB001.
These images are rendered in a custom slider.
If there is no items in the result (a.k.a no image added today), i want to show to the user/visitor, a custom image saying "there is nothing to show".

**What i already have :**

On office 365, I already have the CSWP and the display templates (control and item display templates) set to display the images of today in a slider.
In my Control display template, i have this code :

```
ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultTables";
var items = ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;
if(items.length===0)
{
   console.log("there is no image");
}
```

It should work. But it doesn't.

**What i already tried :**

In fact, after some more investigation, i've tried only to run a `console.log("I'm in Control display template");` at the beginning of the divs, but i can't see a thing in my console. I deduce that when there is no item to show, O365 doesn't even enter the Control display template ! So how am i supposed to tell it that if there is no items, it has to show some custom image ?

I've seen this bunch of code in standard control displya template (like in Control_List):
But I can't make it execute, because O365 doesn't execute the Control code.

```
<!--#_
if (ctx.ClientControl.get_shouldShowNoResultMessage())
{
_#-->
        <div class="_#= noResultsClassName =#_">_#= $noResults =#_</div>
<!--#_
}
_#-->
```

Could you help me with that big problem of mine please?

**Can you help me to discover why O365 does not enter my Control_Slider.html when there is no items given by the query?**

**Thanks a lot** for your time, your patience and your kindness.
At least thanks you to help me understand a little more how O365/SP2013 work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to web part properties and uncheck the 'Dont show anything' box. 
[image]

Comment: Oh my !
Thanks a lot @Shashank, I think my mind got lost after the winter holidays :/
Thank you, i could make it work really well with my try on ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultTables";
var items = ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;
if(items.length===0)
{
   console.log("there is no image");
}